# Is this PowerBuilder stats generation code appropriately object-oriented?

Tags: java, ooad, easerver

I am working on refactoring an existing application written in PowerBuilder and Java and which runs on Sybase EA Server (Jaguar). I am building a small framework to wrap around Jaguar API functions that are available in EA Server. One of the classes is to get runtime statistics from EA Server using the `Monitoring` class.

Without going into too much detail, `Monitoring` is a class in EA Server API that provides Jaguar Runtime Monitoring statistics (actual classes are in C++; EA Server provides a wrapper for these in Java, so they can be accessed through CORBA).

Below is the simplified version of my class. (I made a superclass which I inherit from for getting stats for components, conn. caches, HTTP etc).

```
public class JagMonCompStats {
...
    public void dumpStats(String type, String entity) {

    private String type = "Component";
        private String entity = "web_business_rules";
        private String[] header = {"Active", "Pooled", "invoke"};
        // This has a lot more keys, simplified for this discussion
        private static short[] compKeys = {
            (short) (MONITOR_COMPONENT_ACTIVE.value),
            (short) (MONITOR_COMPONENT_POOLED.value),
            (short) (MONITOR_COMPONENT_INVOKE.value)
        };
        private double[] data = null;

    ...
        /* Call to Jaguar API */
        Monitoring jm = MonitoringHelper.narrow(session.create("Jaguar/Monitoring"));
        data = jm.monitor(type, entity, keys);

    ...

        printStats(entity, header, data);
        ...
    }

    protected void printStats(String entityName, String[] header, double[] data) {

    /* print the header and print data in a formatted way */

    }
}
```

The line `data = jm.monitor` is the call to Jaguar API. It takes the type of the entity, the name of the entity, and the keys of the stats we want. This method returns a double array. I go on to print the header and data in a formatted output.

The program works, but I would like to get experts' opinion on OO design aspect. For one, I want to be able to customize `printStats` to be able to print in different formats (for e.g., full blown report or a one-liner). Apart from this, I am also thinking of showing the stats on a web page or PowerBuilder screen, in which case printStats may not even be relevant. How would you do this in a real OO way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it's quite simple. Don't *print* stats from this class. *Return* them. And let the caller decide how the returned stats should be displayed.

Now that you can get stats, you can create a `OneLinerStatsPrinter`, a `DetailedStatsPrinter`, an `HtmlStatsFormatter`, or whatever you want.

Comment: Wow, that was really fast!!. I really appreciate your feedback. Since I have more than 1 array to return here (actually header, sub header, data), how would you return all these to the caller? I did see some suggestions to return them as object array, but just want to make it would apply here. Thanks again. @Michael thank you for the edit.

Comment: Create a class containing all the information you want to return, stored in a structured way, and providing the necessary accessors, and return an instance of this class.

Comment: You should probably create a class holding the stats in a structure that's understandable by the Printers JB speaks of. You could also pass a "StatsPrinter" interface to your dumpStats method and have it call some printStats method on it. In both cases I think it would make sense to define a class for the stats.